# A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to add a user to sharepoint group with following code

```
serviceUrl= Appweb + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups("+GroupId+")/users?@target='host web'";

$.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    body: "{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' },'LoginName':'i:0#.f|membership|'+email }",
    headers: {"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
   "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
  },
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
       alert('success');
    },
  error: function (data) {
         alert('fail');
    }
});
```

The request goes to error function. Response of the request is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException` and the message is

> A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected

Comment: Answered recently with [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157572/how-to-change-a-view-with-rest-api-web-service-call-in-javascript) post.

You should be using data instead of body.